# Is there a better way to see which function caused a exception other than using catch

Tags: c++, try-catch

I'm having problems with locating the address from which a error occurred, my whole code is running inside of a "try" statement and sadly whenever something is wrong I need to find the error using the old try and fail method by deleting parts of my code. Is there a better way to do it?

My current code:

```cpp
try
{
    do
    {
    if (somefunction)

    if (somefunction2)

    if (somefunction3)

    if (somefunction4)
    }
    while (false);
}
catch (...) 
{
    // todo: somehow get the address where the error occurred
    Logger::Log("Exception\n");
}
```

Comment: The exception message gives you the address where the exception was thrown. Currently, you're ignoring all of the information that is available in the Exception object by just throwing it away and logging the useless information "Exception". Also, depending on the IDE you're using, you can typically view the stack trace when the exception is thrown, which would allow you to see the exact location where that occurred.

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't show you using the Exception  at all. You're just logging the absolutely useless phrase "Exception". The Exception object contains information that you can use, but only if you actually look at it.

Comment: @KenWhite "*The exception message gives you the address where the exception was thrown*" - that is not true for pure C++ exceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution to find out where an exception comes from is to use a unique message within each function. Catch the exception object and print the message. Or perhaps use even a different type of exception which will allow you to efficiently handle each case differently if that's what you want to do.

---

As for getting an "address", the trace of function calls that lead to the current point of execution is called a stacktrace (or backtrace). The stacktrace would contain information such as addresses. Theres no standard way to get a stacktrace yet, although it has been proposed for C++23.

However, once you've caught the exception, the stack will have been "unwound" such that you can't know where the exception came from. What you could do, is get the stack trace in the code that may be throwing (each of them since you  don't know which one is the thrower) and store the trace in the exception. A central place to do that would be within the constructor of a custom exception type. This pattern is common in standard exception handling of modern languages.

---

Lastly, you don't necessarily need to make any changes to the program, if you instead run the program in a debugger and break on a throw, you can get all the information you can possibly get.

Comment: If the OP wants to find the cause of the error without a debugger (not sure why anyone would) the OP should have each of the `somefunction`s throw an exception with a unique message.

Comment: @dmedine Indeed. That's what I said in the first sentence of the answer. But they also have to show the message for it to do any good.

Comment: Indeed you did. My bad.